# Create JSON with specific format using PHP

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I have a table in my server database with the following columns:

```
|---category--|---name---|---description---|
```

So, lets say for example that we have the following data inside the table:

```
|---CategoryA--|---name1---|---description1---|
|---categoryB--|---name2---|---description2---|
|---categoryA--|---name3---|---description3---|
|---categoryA--|---name4---|---description4---|
```

I would like to create a .php file, and when i call it from my Android app i would like to get a JSON as response. The json file would like to have the following format:

```
{
"CategoryA":[
{"name":"name1","description":"description1"},
{"name":"name3","description":"description3"},
{"name":"name4","description":"description4"}
],
"KatigotiaB":[
{"name":"name2","description":"description2"}
]
}
```

I have created a .php file that returns me the data in JSON format, but not in the specific format i want. Here is my .php file:

```
<?php
    header('content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    try {
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=****;dbname=****', '****', '****', array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `db`.`table`;");
    $stmt->execute();

    $results = array();

    while ($obj = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        array_push($results, $obj);
    }

    function replace_unicode_escape_sequence($match) {
        return mb_convert_encoding(pack('H*', $match[1]), 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16BE');
    }

    $str = preg_replace_callback('/\\\\u([0-9a-f]{4})/i', 'replace_unicode_escape_sequence', json_encode($results));


    echo $str;
?>
```

and the result is:

```
[{"category":"CategoryA","name":"name1","description":"description1"},
{"category":"CategoryB","name":"name2","description":"description2"},
{"category":"CategoryA","name":"name3","description":"description3"},
{"category":"CategoryA","name":"name4","description":"description4"}]
```

As i'm an Android developer and my php knowledge is limited, how could i recreate my .php file in order to get the correct JSON format?

UPDATE:
that works

```
 foreach ($nameDescriptionPairs as $nameDescriptionPair) {
            $result[$row['category']][] = array(
                'name'          => $nameDescriptionPair['name'],
                'description'   => $nameDescriptionPair['description']
            );

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution #1 (simple):**

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
$database = '******';
$user = '******';
$password = '******';

$result = [];
try {
    $pdo = new PDO(
        "mysql:host=$host; dbname=$database;",
        $user,
        $password,
        [PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"]
    );

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT category, name, description FROM `YOUR_TABLE_HERE`");
    $stmt->execute();

    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $result[$row['category']][] = [
            'name'          => $row['name'],
            'description'   => $row['description'],
        ];
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($result);
```

**Solution #2 (geeky):**

One note to my code: I used hex conversion to prevent problems with quotes. Thus, even if any column has any number of `"`, the code will work fine.

```
<?php

function hexToStr($hex) {
    $string = '';
    for ($charIter = 0; $charIter < strlen($hex) - 1; $charIter += 2) {
        $string .= chr(hexdec($hex[$charIter] . $hex[$charIter + 1]));
    }
    return $string;
}

//----------------------

$host = 'localhost';
$database = '******';
$user = '******';
$password = '******';

$result = [];    
try {
    $pdo = new PDO(
        "mysql:host=$host; dbname=$database;",
        $user,
        $password,
        [PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"]
    );

        $query = <<<QUERY
    SELECT category, CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT( '{"name":"', hex( name ) , '", "description":"', hex( description ) , '"}' ) ), ']') raw_json
    FROM `YOUR_TABLE_HERE`
    GROUP BY category
QUERY;

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();

    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $nameDescriptionPairs = json_decode($row['raw_json'], true);
        foreach ($nameDescriptionPairs as $nameDescriptionPair) {
            $result[$row['category']][] = [
                'name'          => hexToStr($nameDescriptionPair['name']),
                'description'   => hexToStr($nameDescriptionPair['description'])
            ];
        }
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: Thanks mate, that's a really good piece of code, but unfortunately i'm getting a 500 server error..

Comment: In which line? be sure `QUERY;` has no indent.

Comment: FATAL ERROR syntax error, unexpected '[' on line number 13    [PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"]

Comment: What php version are you using? Try a small test: `var_dump(['a' => 1]);`

Comment: 5.3 should be fine, I think the problem could be in a password (previous line), if you put it directly there instead of using `$password`; also be sure prev. comma is not missing.

Comment: i'm testing it in phptester.net. and the most usual error is FATAL ERROR syntax error, unexpected '[' on line number whatever

Comment: phptester.net 5.3. can't even pass my `var_dump(['a' => 1]);` test.

Comment: as i can see here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php the problem is probably the php version

Comment: You can replace `[...]` to `array(...)` everywhere, but I would upgrade php. Version 5.4 was released 3+ years ago.

Comment: something like: 
 $results = array();

   while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $results=array($row['category']][] =array(
            'name'          => $row['name'],
            'description'   => $row['description'],
        ));
    }

Comment: `$result[$row['category']][] = <...>` is equal to `array_push($result[$row['category']], <...>)`

Answer (score 0):

One major issue is you're setting the content-type to text/html.  You're not printing HTML, this should be set to JSON:

```
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

Not sure if it has any effect, but your callback is unnecessary:

```
$str = preg_replace_callback('/\\\\u([0-9a-f]{4})/i', 'replace_unicode_escape_sequence', json_encode($results));
```

If you truly don't want json_encode to escape unicode, use the `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` option found here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

```
$str = json_encode($results, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Beyond that, you could also use `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` to format it, but line breaks and such shouldn't matter to the app interpreting the JSON if it is made aware that it is JSON (what setting content-type correctly should do).

Comment: I'm really glad for your answer mate, i will correct my .php file as i'm not really familiar with the use of PHP. Do you have any idea how i'll get the specific format i would like to have as response ? Thanks